# How to change or add attributes to html fields via html helper methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I want to disable or enable a textbox based on boolean value, I created this extension method:

```
public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> expression,
            object htmlAttributes,
            bool disabled
            )
        {
            var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
            if (disabled)
            {
                attributes.Add("disabled", "\"disabled\"");
            }
            return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
        }
```

And that how I used:

```
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.MyTextBoxFor(model => model.Body, new { @class = "form-control"}, true)
        </div>
```

but its not working, I'm new to Htmlhelper class, though it's not hard to understand, but I certainly missed something!

**Edit:**

I tried this simple method, to find out the problem:

```
public static IHtmlString MyTextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            //var attrs = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            if (disabled)
            {
                attrs.Add("disabled", "disabled");
                attrs.Add("value", "txxxxxxt");
            }
            return htmlHelper.TextBox("txtbx", attrs);
        }
```

And that has been rendered:
``` <input id="txtbx" name="txtbx" type="text" value="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"> ```

Comment: Maybe it is just a typo in the sample: why do you call the original version of `TextBoxFor` with `htmlAttributes` as a parameter instead of `attributes`?

Comment: I'll pass a Boolean expression, not just `true` or `false`

Comment: try using `IDictionary<string, object> attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);`

Comment: Not working too :(

Comment: Why you need `disabled` parameter, when you can pass it in  `htmlattribute` as `{ disabled= (1==0)}`.

Comment: There are ways of course, but it doesn't solve the current problem, which is "Why is the method not working?"

Comment: Change your return statement to `return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);`

Comment: I fixed this typo and still not working!

Comment: Can you check what HTML is actually generated? Perhaps it has to do with the double " in the dictionary value. (`"\"disabled\""`)

Comment: I tried this also, and even simplified the code to use `TextBox` rather than `TextBoxFor` and the value is renderd but not I supplied but sortof metadata of the value:`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]` I used `value` attribute and `disabled`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for you extension method needs to be

```
public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    if (disabled)
    {
        attrs.Add("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attrs);
}
```

In your first code example, your use of

```
return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
```

is returning the original attributes, not the updated attributes that includes the `disabled` attribute. It should have been

```
return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
```

In your second code example, your using the `TextBox()` method rather that `TextBoxFor()` and the 2nd parameter is the value, not the attributes, and it should have been

```
return htmlHelper.TextBox("txtbx", null, attrs);
```

although that would not have bound to your property because of the incorrect `name` attribute.

Side note: Its a bit unclear why you would ever want to do this. Disabled controls do not submit a value so you may as well just render the value of the property as text in the view. If you do want its value to be submitted, then it should be `readonly`, not `disabled`

Comment: Great, thanks! 
I tried to pass `value` attribute but didn't rendered , do you know why, though attribute like `style` is working fine. I tried this:
`@Html.MyTextBoxFor(model => model.Body, new { @class = "form-control", style="background-color:yellow;", value="hurray"}, true)`

Comment: Why would you want to do that. You never set the `value` attribute (or the `name` attribute) when using `HtmlHelper` methods (the methods set that attribute based on value of the property). So if `model.Body="hurray"` then it will be generated correctly (setting the `value` attribute screws up model binding)